# android: apdfviewer issue

Tags: android-ndk

I start working on pdf render.I need to open the pdf file inside the app,i check out the lib available in android like droidreader,apv etc all work slow and try to convert the pdf into images then display.then i choose the apdfviewer,i install the apk that works fine but svn check out code show the error logd

```
`04-16 12:09:02.420: WARN/System.err(412): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library libpoppler-jni not found
04-16 12:09:02.420: WARN/System.err(412):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
04-16 12:09:02.429: WARN/System.err(412):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
04-16 12:09:02.429: WARN/System.err(412):     at com.googlecode.apdfviewer.PDFDocument.<clinit>(PDFDocument.java:105)
04-16 12:09:02.440: WARN/System.err(412):     at com.googlecode.apdfviewer.PDFView.openUri(PDFView.java:272)
04-16 12:09:02.440: WARN/System.err(412):     at com.googlecode.apdfviewer.PDFViewerActivity.onCreate(PDFViewerActivity.java:74)
04-16 12:09:02.440: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-16 12:09:02.440: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-16 12:09:02.450: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-16 12:09:02.450: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-16 12:09:02.450: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-16 12:09:02.460: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 12:09:02.460: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 12:09:02.460: WARN/System.err(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-16 12:09:02.470: WARN/System.err(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 12:09:02.470: WARN/System.err(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-16 12:09:02.470: WARN/System.err(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-16 12:09:02.470: WARN/System.err(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-16 12:09:02.480: WARN/System.err(412):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 12:09:02.480: WARN/dalvikvm(412): No implementation found for native Lcom/googlecode/apdfviewer/PDFDocument;.native_init (Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
04-16 12:09:02.480: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(412): Shutting down VM
04-16 12:09:02.490: WARN/dalvikvm(412): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: native_init
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.googlecode.apdfviewer.PDFDocument.native_init(Native Method)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.googlecode.apdfviewer.PDFDocument.<init>(PDFDocument.java:41)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.googlecode.apdfviewer.PDFView.openUri(PDFView.java:272)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.googlecode.apdfviewer.PDFViewerActivity.onCreate(PDFViewerActivity.java:74)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-16 12:09:02.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest to if any other good lib available?do need to have install the NDK for it
I am new in android,thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it shows that u are not having JNI folder in your project & u may not have the native library file("example.so") of it.
(.so) is the extension of library file.
to build this .so file u must need android NDK & a software called "cygwin" which helps to build the native file from JNI folder